# iOS Microphone not working or not sending the voice through webrtc when the call is answered from locked screen

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, voip, callkit

I am using Webrtc and Callkit for calling. Everything works properly when app is foreground, but if the screen is locked and I answer the call audio only works on my side ( I can hear the audio but my voice is not sent).

When the user enters the app everything is fixed.

All the background settings and capabilities are set properly.

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
   <array>
        <string>audio</string>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
        <string>voip</string>
    </array>
```

I tried configuring audio with both RTCAudioSession and AVAudioSession but in both cases it works the same way.

Solved: 
I was putting mediastream in RTCPeerConnection and now I am adding RTCMediaStreamTracks instead

Comment: [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366289/ios-audio-not-working-during-call-answered-when-phone-is-locked-webrtc-used-for) I think about the same issue

Comment: @Signo It's not exactly the same in this question audio is not working on both sides. still I tried the solution provided in this answer but couldnt fix it

Comment: @EleneAkhvlediani Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @codeGeek I updated webrtc to the newest version and also, in past I was putting mediastream in RTCPeerConnection and now  I am adding RTCMediaStreamTracks instead ( for audio and video )

Comment: @EleneAkhvlediani I tried doing the same as you said. Still no voice coming from iphone

Comment: having same issue with webRTC and Callkit, when app going to background mic stopped working, only the speaker working.

Answer (score 1):

**Please Note that I share my code and its about to my needs and I share for reference. you need to change it according to your need.**

when you receive voip notification create new incident of your webrtc handling class, and
add this two lines to code block because enabling audio session from voip notification fails

```
RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().useManualAudio = true
RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().isAudioEnabled = false
```

didReceive method;

```
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
               let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
               
        
     
                   if(payload.dictionaryPayload["hangup"] == nil && state != .active
                   ){
                       
               
                     Globals.voipPayload = payload.dictionaryPayload as! [String:Any] // I pass parameters to Webrtc handler via Global singleton to create answer according to sdp sent by payload.
                        
                       RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().useManualAudio = true
                       RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().isAudioEnabled = false
                       
                     
                      
                     Globals.sipGateway = SipGateway() // my Webrtc and Janus gateway handler class
                    
                       
                     Globals.sipGateway?.configureCredentials(true) // I check janus gateway credentials stored in Shared preferences and initiate websocket connection and create peerconnection 
to my janus gateway which is signaling server for my environment
                    
                       
                  initProvider() //Crating callkit provider
                       
                       self.update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value:String(describing: payload.dictionaryPayload["caller_id"]!))
                          Globals.callId = UUID()
             
                       let state = UIApplication.shared.applicationState
                       
                      
                          Globals.provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with:Globals.callId , update: self.update, completion: { error in
                           
                           
                          })
                       
                
               }
              
           }
    
        
        func  initProvider(){
            let config = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "ulakBEL")
            config.iconTemplateImageData = UIImage(named: "ulakbel")!.pngData()
            config.ringtoneSound = "ringtone.caf"
                   // config.includesCallsInRecents = false;
                    config.supportsVideo = false
            
            Globals.provider = CXProvider(configuration:config )
            Globals.provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
             update = CXCallUpdate()
             update.hasVideo = false
             update.supportsDTMF = true
      
        }
```

modify your didActivate and didDeActive delegate functions like below,

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didActivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
       print("CallManager didActivate")
       RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().audioSessionDidActivate(audioSession)
       RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().isAudioEnabled = true
      // self.callDelegate?.callIsAnswered()
    
 
   }

   func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, didDeactivate audioSession: AVAudioSession) {
       print("CallManager didDeactivate")
RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().audioSessionDidDeactivate(audioSession)
       RTCAudioSession.sharedInstance().isAudioEnabled = false
    
 
   }
```

in Webrtc handler class configure media senders and audiosession

```
private func createPeerConnection(webRTCCallbacks:PluginHandleWebRTCCallbacksDelegate) {
   
        let rtcConfig =  RTCConfiguration.init()
        rtcConfig.iceServers = server.iceServers
        rtcConfig.bundlePolicy = RTCBundlePolicy.maxBundle
        rtcConfig.rtcpMuxPolicy = RTCRtcpMuxPolicy.require
        rtcConfig.continualGatheringPolicy = .gatherContinually
        rtcConfig.sdpSemantics = .planB
        
        let constraints = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: nil,
                                                 optionalConstraints: ["DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement":kRTCMediaConstraintsValueTrue])
           
        pc = sessionFactory.peerConnection(with: rtcConfig, constraints: constraints, delegate: nil)
        self.createMediaSenders()
        self.configureAudioSession()
        
   
        
      if webRTCCallbacks.getJsep() != nil{
        handleRemoteJsep(webrtcCallbacks: webRTCCallbacks)
        }
      
    }
```

mediaSenders;

```
private func createMediaSenders() {
        let streamId = "stream"
        
        // Audio
        let audioTrack = self.createAudioTrack()
        self.pc.add(audioTrack, streamIds: [streamId])
        
        // Video
      /*  let videoTrack = self.createVideoTrack()
        self.localVideoTrack = videoTrack
        self.peerConnection.add(videoTrack, streamIds: [streamId])
        self.remoteVideoTrack = self.peerConnection.transceivers.first { $0.mediaType == .video }?.receiver.track as? RTCVideoTrack
        
        // Data
        if let dataChannel = createDataChannel() {
            dataChannel.delegate = self
            self.localDataChannel = dataChannel
        }*/
    }

  private func createAudioTrack() -> RTCAudioTrack {
        let audioConstrains = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: nil, optionalConstraints: nil)
        let audioSource = sessionFactory.audioSource(with: audioConstrains)
        let audioTrack = sessionFactory.audioTrack(with: audioSource, trackId: "audio0")
        return audioTrack
    }
```

audioSession ;

```
private func configureAudioSession() {
        self.rtcAudioSession.lockForConfiguration()
        do {
            try self.rtcAudioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord.rawValue)
            try self.rtcAudioSession.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.voiceChat.rawValue)
        } catch let error {
            debugPrint("Error changeing AVAudioSession category: \(error)")
        }
        self.rtcAudioSession.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
```

**Please consider that because I worked with callbacks and delegates code includes delegates and callback chunks. you can ignore them accordingly!!**

FOR REFERENCE You can also check the example at this [link](https://github.com/stasel/WebRTC-iOS/)